# Zapier Extract Country Code from Line of Text with Multiple Seperators

Tags: zapier, drift

I am trying to use the Zapier formatter to extract a country code from a line of text I am getting from a connected app (Drift).

The string comes into Zapier like this:

{"city":"Kissimmee","region":"Florida","country":"US","countryName":"United States","postalCode":"34747","latitude":55.5555,"longitude":-55.5555}

I am trying to get it to extract just the two-letter country code portion of that line.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am now trying to use the extract pattern function, but my Python Expression skills are weak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use a pattern:

```
country\":\"(.*?)\"
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQUzv.png)

Comment: This is perfect.  I prefer this method to just have it as a single step.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 steps with the Formatter.

Split at country":" and keep the second segment, then split at " and keep the first segment.

screenshot:

[image]